# Spring boot - Request method 'POST' not supported.

Tags: spring-boot, crud

please i have this error when trying to create a customer. Can some one help me? May be i am missing some thing. I have even try to change the @PostMapping to @RequestMapping till yet. Thks

**My Controller code**

> ```
> `@PostMapping("CREATE_CUSTOMER_ENDPOINT")
>    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
>    @ApiResponses(value = {
>         @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "The Customer was Created", response = CustomerDto.class),
>         @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request", response = ResponseError.class),
>         @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Unexpected error")
> })
> ```

```
  public ResponseEntity createCustomer(final HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody CustomerDto customerDto)
{
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()){
        log.debug("[CustomerResource] POST {} : Creating customer ", CREATE_CUSTOMER_ENDPOINT);
    }

    if(customerDto.getUidpk()!=null) {
        ResponseError error  = new ResponseError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.getReasonPhrase(), "A customer Already exist with an Uidpk");
        log.error("[CustomerResource] The customer Already exist ({}) with an Uidpk", customerDto.getUidpk());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, null,    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    CustomerDto result = customerService.createCustomer(customerDto);
    log.debug("[CustomerResource] Customer created ({})", result.getUidpk());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HeaderUtil.putLocationHeader(request.getRequestURL().toString() + "/" + result.getUidpk()), HttpStatus.CREATED);

} `
```

**My endpoints**

`private static final String CUSTOMER_SEARCH_USER_ID_ENDPOINT = "/customers/{userId:.+}";
    private static final String CREATE_CUSTOMER_ENDPOINT= "/customer";
    private static final String UPDATE_CUSTOMER_ENDPOINT= "/customer";
    private static final String DELETE_CUSTOMER_ENDPOINT = CREATE_CUSTOMER_ENDPOINT + "/{uidpk}";`

This is the response of Postman
[Postman sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSi6u.png)

Comment: does it have to do with you annotation ,  @PostMapping("CREATE_CUSTOMER_ENDPOINT") , i think you want this -->   @PostMapping(CREATE_CUSTOMER_ENDPOINT)

Comment: mistake sorry. i corrected it and i ha a new error in Postman :     "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "error_description": [
        "Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported"
    ]
}

Comment: add the headers in your request , and it will solve it , do validate your JSON value using any online validator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send JSON payloads in HTTP request, you need to specify `Content-Type` HTTP header with value `application/json`.

Comment: He should also be using the `consumes` and `produces` members of `@PostMapping` to that effect.

Comment: My request is working well. But when i got into my createCustomer method as mention recently, it goes into this condition     if(customerDto.getUidpk()!=null) and replies "A customer Already exist with an Uidpk". Am using the H2 DATABASE. My database is empty. Please   i am really confused. Any Proposition Thk you